# jQuery Tools: wait accordion slide to finish, then show images in accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools

I'm using jQuery Tool's tabs an accordion as per here: http://www.jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/accordion.htm

The whole thing is activated with

Code:

```
$("#accordion").tabs(
  "#accordion div.pane",
  {tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex: null}
);
```

While the content of the panes is revealed with a slide function, in my setup, I would like the images within the pane to be shown only once the slide animation has finished, plus the image of the current tab should be hidden again as soon as an accordion header is clicked. I've fiddled around but couldn't get it to work.

I thought of setting the images to display:none; and then change them to display once the rest of the content is revealed?

Can I do this by adding something to the above code? Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you'll want to do a custom animation. It should be pretty straight forward.

```
  $.tools.tabs.addEffect("custom", function(tabIndex, done) {

  // hide any images
  $("#accordion img").hide();

  // hide all panes and show the one that is clicked, on complete show images
  this.getPanes().hide().eq(tabIndex).show('fast',function(){
      //show the images again now that the animation has finished
      $("#accordion img").show();
  });

  // the supplied callback must be called after the effect has finished its job
  done.call();
  });
```

Then you can replace the animation effect 'slide' with 'custom'.

Comment: Thanks, that works like a charm. Shame I can't vote this further up. Unfortunately it doesn't slide so much now, i.e. the current pane collapsing while the new one is expanding. Otherwise, many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> I thought of setting the images to display:none; and then change them
>   to display once the rest of the content is revealed?

Thats how I would do it.  display:none on all images, then:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#accordian img").show();
});
```

The images won't be displayed until the entire document has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to open the pane of the accordion and then show the image that's inside it, have a look into the [change](http://jqueryui.com/demos/accordion/#event-change) event of the accordion, this event could notice you when the pane is opened. And yes, you will need to set the image to be hidden first.

Answer (score 0):

You can bind directly to the 'load' event of the tabs...

```
$("#accordion").tabs(
  "#accordion div.pane",
  {tabs: 'h2', effect: 'slide', initialIndex: null,
    load: function(event, ui){
      $('accordian img').show();
    }
  }
);
```

Now when the tab loads complete (DOM is ready), it will show the images in the div, and ONLY AFTER the `DOM has been updated to completely reflect the changes to the elements in the tab`.